# Drupal 8 Remove Field labels and values from Content Type view

Tags: php, html, drupal-8

I have a site setup, and I noticed some [odd text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltC6c.jpg) showing up on one of my pages. I went into the admin panel and took a closer look. It turns out that these are [fields inside the content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P5ux.jpg) of these pages. It takes these field titles and puts them on the actual page view along with their values. Anyone know how to fix this? I want to remove the label for some things such as Date, but I want to hide the actual content as well (for example the 20 from sort order).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of this can be done in the manage display tab. (structure -> content types -> your content type -> manage display tab) Here you can set the labels to hidden and what fields you want to display. If you do not want to show certain fields, you can drag the fields to the disabled section.

[content type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTiW7.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have to assume that the 1st screenshot is taken from the views result page.

It looks like you need to change your view from showing content (rendered entity maybe) to showing fields. And then select specific fields you want to show along with *how* you want them to be shown. Namely — remove labels.